# Excel Graph API set date with correct format

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using Microsoft's Graph API for Excel and trying to set the date in a cell

I call the endpoint using the `PATCH` request.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/XXXXXXXX/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1')
```

The body content is as follows

```
formulas: [
  [2/1/2017]
]
```

The problem I have is Excel re-arranges this to 1/2/2017.

How would I tell the Graph API the correct date format to use, or set the session's locale so it doesn't change my file's date format.

Also my date format in the Excel file itself is DD/MM/YYYY, but Excel will keep changing it to MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: This might be an obvious question but can you not change the format in your excel file to a customer `DD/MM/YYY` format?

Comment: The excel file already has the DD/MM/YYYY format. Setting it with the graph api alters the format.